# How i can know is fragment visible from a service

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-cloud-messaging, android-service

I'm using GCM Cloud Listener Service for catching some notification from my server and show it at status bar via `NotificationCompat`

For some reason i don't what to show my notification if my fragment (with list of some updatable items) is showing now.

What is the best way to check is my fragment visible now from `CloudListenerService`?

I think i can use `Application` for store current state of fragment:

In application class:

```
 public class ClientApplication extends Application {    
        public static WeakReference<Fragment> currentFragment;
```

In my `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    ClientApplication.fragment = new WeakReference<>(this);

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    ClientApplication.fragment = null;
    super.onPause();
}
```

In my `Cloud listener service`:

```
if(ClientApplication.fragment.get() != null && ClientApplication.fragment.get().isVisible()) {
    dosth();
```

Answer (score 6):

in Fragment :
add this

```
public MyFragment extends Fragment {

public  static boolean active = false;
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    active = true;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    active = false;
}
```

in service :

```
if (MyFragment.active) {
       //DO STUFF
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can track your Activity/Fragment using the Activity or Fragment Lifecycle of your app. For instance you can save if your activity/fragment is visible in a SharedPreference or using a Class variable.

Another way is by asking to the ActivityManager if your Activity is currently running, or asking to the FragmentManager if an specific fragment is visible:

```
MyFragmentClass f = (MyFragmentClass) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("youFragmentTag");


if (f != null && test.isVisible()) {
     // It's Visible
}
else {
    // No visible
}
```